# Identifying unique visitor using only info that can be gathered through the browser?

Tags: authentication, web-browser

There is a site that allows a voter to vote for their favorite nominee once a day for a certain amount of days. While entering a vote, the only info given is the ballot choice you choose and nothing else.

If you are to go back and vote again, there is a message saying "please wait until next day to vote again". However if you just simply use a different internet browser you can enter another ballot.

I'm wondering what they are using to identify the voter through the browser and if they can tell when a single voter is entering multiple votes through different browsers. Also is there an even more simple/easier way that a voter could be doing this without having to use multiple browsers?

Comment: Probably cookies. Try an incognito window or clear the cookie for the site to confirm.

Comment: "if they can tell when a single voter is entering multiple votes through different browsers" the IP address helps detect this, even if (CG)NAT means that there will be some false positives.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If the voters are mostly expected to be from the same locality, I'd expect CGNAT to create lots of false positives.

Comment: Regarding use of the *same* browser (but not only), you might be interested in EFF's Panopticlick project: https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf

Comment: This project https://github.com/jonasstrehle/supercookie allow you to identifie a browser. It is working even if you restart your OS or use a VPN. Using favicons, to recognise you by the get request your browser will do to multiple domains loading new favicons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes after clearing the browser data (history, site data,  cookies,  cache...etc.) it is possible to enter another vote.

Comment: Without a serious authentication scheme, it is not possible to securely identify *somebody*. A cookie is a simple way to identify a browser, as long as the cookie is not cleared. And you should be aware that it is possible (for example using Python code) to fake a browser, send some GET and PUT request to enter a vote and forget any cookie. That way you can start again the program every nth minute to enter a new vote. It can be detected through heuristics on the delays between action, and the counter measure is to precisely add randomized delays...

Comment: ...  Long story made short: a cookie is a simple but not a reliable way.